# R Shiny: side by side verbatimTextoutput()

Tags: r, shiny, formatting

I have

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Interactive CLicks"),   
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot",hover = "plot_hover",click= "plot_click", dblclick = "plot_db_click",height = 500, width = 1600 )),
    br(),
    fluidRow(column(width = 12), verbatimTextOutput("info_hover"),
             fluidRow(column(6, verbatimTextOutput("info_click")), column(6, offset = 6, verbatimTextOutput("info_db_click"))),    
    verbatimTextOutput("double_to_single_click"))
  
)




## server.R
server <- function( input, output, session){
  
  #Click Points
  single.source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=data.frame(x=c(1,1),  y=c(1,1)))
  double.source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=data.frame(x=c(1,1),  y=c(1,1)))
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    single.source_coords$xy[2,] <- c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_db_click, {
    double.source_coords$xy[2,] <- c(input$plot_db_click$x, input$plot_db_click$y)
  })
  
  
  ## RenderPlot 
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    plot(1, 1,
         xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
    
    #Click points
    points( single.source_coords$xy[2,1], single.source_coords$xy[2,2], cex=3, pch=17)
    points( double.source_coords$xy[2,1], double.source_coords$xy[2,2], cex=3, pch=17)
    segments(x0 =single.source_coords$xy[2,1], y0 = single.source_coords$xy[2,2], x1 =  double.source_coords$xy[2,1], y1 = double.source_coords$xy[2,2], col = "darkred", lwd = 2, lty = 3)
    
    
  })        
  
  output$info_click <- renderText({
    paste0("Single Click Multiple", "\nX=", single.source_coords$xy[2,1], "     Y= ",single.source_coords$xy[2,2])
  })
  
  output$info_db_click <- renderText({
    paste0("Double Click Multiple", "\nX=", double.source_coords$xy[2,1], "     Y= ",double.source_coords$xy[2,2])
  })
  
  output$info_hover <- renderText({
    paste0("Hover Click Multiple", "\nX=", input$plot_hover$x*2, "     Y= ",input$plot_hover$y*2)
  })
  
  output$double_to_single_click <- renderText({
    paste0("Double to Signle", "\nX=", double.source_coords$xy[2,1]/single.source_coords$xy[2,1], "     Y= ",double.source_coords$xy[2,2]/single.source_coords$xy[2,2])
  })
  
  
}

### Run Application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

i would like to have the `single click multiple` and `double click multiple` `verbatimTextOutput()` boxes side by side. What am I doing wrong?

If I replace with

```
  fluidRow(column(width = 12), "info_hover",
           fluidRow(column(6, "info_click"), column(6, offset = 6, "info_db_click")),    
           "double_to_single_click")
```

it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `offset` seems to give the desired result, given that according to the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/column.html), offset is the number of columns to offset from the **end of the previous column**.

```
fluidRow(column(width = 12), verbatimTextOutput("info_hover"),
           fluidRow(column(6, verbatimTextOutput("info_click")), column(6, verbatimTextOutput("info_db_click"))),    
           verbatimTextOutput("double_to_single_click"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `fluidRow` is:

```
fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 6,
    UI elements in the column (comma-separated if multiple)
  ),
  column(
    width = 6,
    UI elements in the column (comma-separated if multiple)
  )
)
```

So you need to do:

```
fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 6,
    verbatimTextOutput("xxx")
  ),
  column(
    width = 6,
    verbatimTextOutput("yyy")
  )
)
```